# Horizontal Scroller with centered scrollbar

Tags: css, sass, scrollbar, overflow

How would you go about creating something like this:

[image]

The idea is you've got a horizontal scrollable section, and wanting to show the scrollbar underneath. But, you only want the scrollbar to be the width of the main container, centered to page.

Linked below a jsfiddle of how I've approached it, but no luck with trying to keep the scrollbar only centered. Tried using a max-width, but doesn't seem to have any affect. Any ideas?

```
.scroll-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding-bottom: 24px;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  
  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 16px;
  }
  &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #eee;
    // you'd think max-width or something here would be the solution
  }
  &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 4px solid #eee;
  }
}

.scroll-wrapper > *:first-child {
  margin-left: 80px;
}

.scroll-item {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin-right: 16px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tzdcay9r/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it… can use margins on the scrollbar-track ‍♂️

https://jsfiddle.net/8snuamhv/1/

```
&::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #eee;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
}
```

Or if you want something a bit more dynamic, for example to match a container size, you can use a calc() function to work out the margin values.

```
  $containerSize: 1120px;

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-left: calc((100vw - $containerSize) / 2);
    margin-right: calc((100vw - $containerSize) / 2);

    @media (max-width: $containerSize) {
      margin-left: 16px;
      margin-right: 16px;
    }
  }
```